# mobile optimization CSS

Tags: css, mobile, overflow

So I am just starting out in FE and found a really cool parralex animation via CSS that I have applied to my site.

I am happy with the desktop, but on mobile I lose the text boxes for some of the slides.

I tried to add the @media to specify changes for mobile screen sizes, and it works ok on Pixel 3, but on Iphone it is still cutting off. I suspect it is something to do with the overflow - but I cannot seem to fix it. I have tried a couple if things, I am not starting to think I just need to do a mobile style sheet. As I am new to the game I thought I would post on here to see if there is a quick fix!

Thanks,

D

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>

<style>

html {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
    perspective: 1px;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  font-family: 'Lora', serif;
}


h1 {
   font-size: 250%
}

p {
  font-size: 140%;
  line-height: 150%;
  color: #333;
}

.slide {
  position: relative;
  padding: 25vh 10%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0 -1px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
    transform-style: inherit;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 5px 5px #808080;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 35%;
  width: 320px;
  height: 240px;
  transform: translateZ(.25px) scale(.75) translateX(-94%) translateY(-100%) rotate(2deg);
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: rgba(240,230,220, .7);
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
}

img:last-of-type {
  transform: translateZ(.4px) scale(.6) translateX(-104%) translateY(-40%) rotate(-5deg);
}

.slide:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
}

.title {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 3%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: rgba(240,230,220, .7);
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
}

.slide:nth-child(2n) .title {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.slide:nth-child(2n+1) .title {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: 0;
}

.slide, .slide:before {
  background: 50% 50% / cover;
}

.header {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 175%;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 5px 5px #008000;
}

#title {
  background-image: url("code1.jpg");
  z-index:2;
}

#title h1 {
 transform: translateZ(.25px) scale(.75);
 transform-origin: 50% 100%;
 color: #fff;
 text-shadow: 0 5px 5px #008000;
}

#slide1:before {
  background-image: url("code2.jpg");
  transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);

}

#slide2 {
  background-image: url("code3.jpg");
  z-index:2;
}

#slide3:before {
  background-image: url("dark.jpg");
  transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
}

#slide4 {
  background: #222;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 1020px) {
  #title, #slide1, #slide2, #slide3, #slide4 {
    float: none;
    width: auto;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: scroll;
  }
}


</style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="title" class="slide header">
    <h1>
    </h1>
  </div>
  <div id="slide1" class="slide">
    <div class="title">
      <h1>About me</h1>
<p></p>    
</div>
    </div>
    <div id="slide2" class="slide">
    <div class="title">
      <h1>Skill set</h1>
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <img src="code1.jpg">
    <img src="hype.jpg">




   </div>
   <div id="slide3" class="slide">

   <div class="title">

   <h1>Why choose me?</h1>

   <p></p>

   </div>
   </div>

   <div id="slide4" class="slide header">

   <h1></h1>

   <p></p>

  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set z-index for the title, and remember to set position to z-index work well

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1020px) {
  .slide .title {
     position: relative;
     z-index: 5;
  }
}
```

Comment: Jenny, thanks so much! Works perfectly on my Pixel now, will get to testing on some other devices!

Comment: Hmm - it still does not fix on IOS? Tried on ipad and iphone and it seems to hide text and box on the first and third slide! But your fix works perfectly on android! Am I just being lazy or is there a fix for this?